# Equivalence in height between monitors 21:9 and 16:9

Tags: monitors

I would like to know what the height equivalence is, which should be taken into account for a 21: 9 monitor versus a 16: 9 monitor.

[image: monitor size]

For example, a monitor 21: 9 of 24 ", this one has less height than one of the same size in inches of one with format 16: 9.

[image: monitor size 2]

**PD:** *Remembering that the size is taken mainly by the diagonal*

Comment: Sorry, I think I made a mistake, it's not about resolution, it's about size in terms of height. I'm going to edit the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the site you want and need :)

https://screendimensions.com/

You can add your own dimension in pixels, and the diagonal. 
You then click in the plus sign, and it will add the screen you defined. You can do this multiple times, the tool will compare the screens. [image: First screencap]

[image: Second screencap]

Comment: Good tool, but just show size for mobile phone and tablet

Comment: You can add any dimension you want yourself :)

Comment: Some examples you hace?? Some screen capture?

Comment: @PedroMiguelPimientaMorales done :)

Comment: Thanks, really good, just nerd prove and save money for the black friday :)